# Using CookieContainer with HttpRequest class

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

I am working with HttpRequest class and i have two Action in my controller like below!

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    public ActionResult Start()
    {
       var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sample.com");
       request.CookieContainer = viewModel.cookieJar;
       request.Method = "GET";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Start (StartModel startModel)
    {
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sample.com/another");
      request.CookieContainer = viewModel.cookieJar;
      request.Method = "POST";
    }
}
```

I have a button on my view and its posts values getting my first actions response to second action's model. But Cookiecontainer is refreshes when enter the second action.

Well i have to send cookies came from first request to second request. How can i?

Comment: A controller gets instantiated for each request, so each request to your site starts with a new `CookieContainer`. You'll have to find another way to persist this information, for example by storing the cookies from the remote site in the user's session.

Comment: You could try to create Your own class which contains `CookieContainer`, register it as Singleton in services and injecting it with Dependency injection library.

Comment: @Genotypek ah... let me try, but it seems kinda hard!